# Using SQL Server to Export one table to data from a database to the same table in another database on the same SQL instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Server Management Studio Export Data from one database to another on the same server. Everything ran
fine except the table below is taking hours to run. I have large tables that have 20,000+ records, but none
have taken as long as this. This table contains about 18,000 records.

Right now I am trying it again and only copying this table so no other tasks should be running.

When I select the tables to exprot from database A to MyDatabase, I check the edit mappings and enable identity insert,
which I have done for other tables and everything was fine.

Right the copying dialog box is saying "Executing" and "In Progress...".

```
USE [myDatabase]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [errors] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [productname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [product_id] [varchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Why is this taken so long and what should I do to attempt to fix it?

Comment: 20k *rows* is nothing, I would check what other processes are running and might be blocking, both source and target DBs

Comment: All the other tables ran super smoothly so it is something with that table but not sure why.

Comment: Check the wait stats https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current and check for blocking https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-who-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Are there any triggers on the target table?

Comment: How many gigabytes are in `errors`, the `varchar(max)` column? Indexes? Foreign keys? Full-text search on `errors`?

Comment: The statement above is the entire table creation, so no FKs or anything special. The target table is a copy of the source table and is being created from scratch. It might be GB is errors which I should check on. No triggers either. Thx @David Browne, that is quite helpful info to look at.

Comment: It's the size of the table - its TableSizeInKB=6204400 and IndexSizeInKB=8 which is pretty large

Comment: What's the max length of the text in the 'errors' column?